# Is it possible to set view visibility as false if until complete view is rendered

Tags: sapui5

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("oui5mvc.sdto").setVisible(false); //Not working
sap.ui.jsview("oui5mvc.sdto").setVisible(false); //Not Working
this.getView().byId("oui5mvc.sdto").setVisible(false); // Not Working
```

Is it possible to hide a view till I show busy indicator as it looks ugly in background to show containers with borders/labels/buttons till the data is populated. So I am trying to hide the view and once data comes I am setting it to true. But that do not seem to work. Is there any way I can do that or atleast if I can blur background till busy indicator is there.

Comment: Would be interesting to know why your code doesn't work. What type of error do you get?

Comment: `this.getView().setVisible(false/true)` works and moreover as the busy indicator is part of view so it also becomes invisible. Is there any other way to make background blur while busy indicator is on.

Comment: already tried lazy loading? --> https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/cdab0a1123514cc08cf2c8deb22f312e.html